# Google GeoCode differences between XHR Request and Browser

Tags: node.js, google-maps, request, google-geocoder, geocode

No results using the GeoCode Google API.

URL : `https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=13+Avenue+FR%20DE%20LA%20JOSNIERE+LE%20DORAT&key=<KEY>`

Doing a XHR Request (or request => npm), return nothing.
But when I go to this link with my browser it's working well.

I already tried to change the header request by this :

Request Headers:

[image]

Code request with headers:

[image]

No way, any ideas ?

Comment: Maybe CORS issue? Can you see any response?

Comment: @xomena how it could be a CORS issue ? There is no web server in my app, only one request.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I guess is that is unknown to Google. Sometimes it happens. If you want to check your request sender use the request below.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=key

For the address you provide gave me zero results. So basically Google doesn't know about the address.

Response for your request

> {
>      "results" : [],
>      "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
>   }

Comment: There is a response for my request : https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=13+Avenue+FR%20DE%20LA%20JOSNIERE+LE%20DORAT

Comment: Are you about the address that you provided? seems google can't provide a geocode for that

Answer (score 0):

https://geocode.xyz/13+Avenue+FR%20DE%20LA%20JOSNIERE+LE%20DORAT

Returns:

- France x,y z: 46.21766,1.07657
- 13 AVENUE DE LA JOSNIERE, Le Dorat, France 87210 » Confidence Score: 0.5